# Displaying field collections loop in Content Type TPL file for drupal 7

Tags: drupal, collections, drupal-7, field

I have a content type "about" created in Drupal 7. I have a field collection named "field_usf_projects" which is set to unlimited and contains 2 fields, "usf_title" and "usf_description". Now I want to run a for loop which retrieves the field_usf_projects and then displays 2 fields namely ("usf_title" and "usf_description") inside a ul - li structure.

I have gone through many links but cannot find a working solution. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, on hook_node_view you can use the entity wrapper to get the fields

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // Check if the node is type 'about'.
  if ($node->type != 'about') {
    return;
  }

  // Get the contents of the node using entity wrapper.
  $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

  // Get the contents of the field collection.
  $values = $node_wrapper->field_usf_projects;

  // Loop field_usf_projects.
  foreach ($values as $item) {
    // Print the values of the fields.
    var_dump($item->usf_title->value());
    var_dump($item->usf_description->value());
  }
}
```

Instead of dumping, you can add the markup for your

A nicer thing to do would be use the hook_preprocess_node to add the markup straight into the $variables, and print them via template.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7

Comment: Hello Marcelo, 

I do not get the fields which are set up. I get the following output when I print the values array. Check it out at http://pastebin.com/aM8sVNdN

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how I'm handling this, event it's a bit dirty and I'm risking to be crucified, but it works for me. If you are inside node template you have $node object. Print it with `print_r` or similar way and just follow the structure of output to get to your data. It will probably be something like:

```
$node->field_usf_title['und']...
```

If you don't have that $node object find node id and load the node with

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

first.

Comment: I am not getting these fields. Also, when I have the array printed out, following is what I get

http://pastebin.com/vt5cg5vx

Comment: But that's it. In some cases you have available all node fields, but in some you don't. But you have "nid" field so you can load whole node by your self, as I explainded above. So, $node = node_load($node->nid); and you'll get full node.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally fed up with Field collection. I cannot get any data. I have used Multifield which is way too much better than Field collection. Please see it at https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield

Let me know what is better multi field or Field Collection.

Thanks!